# Can classmethod/staticmethod access attributes of initial caller?

Tags: python, oop, async-await

I am learning and try to write python api client for some third-party API
For simplicity:
I have 2 classes: Session, EndpointGroup:

```py
class Session:
    def __init__(self, token=None):
        self.token = token
        self.group1 = EndpointGroup

class EndpointGroup:
    @classmethod
    def ping(cls, token, **kwargs):
        return f'Calling ping() with params: {kwargs} and token {token}'
```

I have many EndpointGroups which contain same-category api calls.
I want to give end-user to call methods like this:

```py
session = Session(token='123')
r = session.group1.ping(data='somedata') # Calling ping with params: {'data':'somedata'} and token 123
```

I want to pass token to callable automaticly/implicitly so user don't have to on each call pass to callable something like session.group1.ping(data='somedata', token=session.token)
Is there "built-in" solution to do it? Because with _*getattribute*_ I only can access EndpointGroup class but not method which is called.
**What i have already tried:**

- Creating instances of EndpointGroup passing session/token (Don't like solution because it creates too many instances for each single session) with _*getattribute*_
- Let Session inherit EndpointGroup methods, but then I lose desirable "interface" like **session.groupN.method_X** to **session.method_X**
- Make in EndpointGroup class attr 'token' and On each call change it so method can access this token of current caller(session) (Don't like this solution because this way I will not be able to work asynchronously)

Comment: "Don't like solution because it creates too many instances for each single session" not really sure I understand this concern

Comment: Your first attempt is probably the right path. Instead of creating a new instance each time you call `EndpointGroup`, though, you'll want to "memoize" it so that it can return an existing object if one already exists for the given argument. (I.e., `EndpointGroup(x) is EndpointGroup(y)` is true if `x == y`.)

Comment: @chepner  currently i have code using that way, but for me in seems wrong. for example: have 20 EndpointGroups instances per 1 instance session. So, if some hypotetical web service will have 1000 sessions then it will have 20000 instances of endpointgroups. This situation does not seem right

Answer (score 1):

You can use some proxies to be like a partial function:

```py
class PartialProxy:
    def __init__(self, method, **kwargs):
        self.method = method
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        
    def __call__(self, **kwargs):
        k = {**self.kwargs, **kwargs}
        return self.method(**k)
        
class PartialProxyProxy:
    def __init__(self, klass, **kwargs):
        self.klass = klass
        self.kwargs = kwargs
    
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return PartialProxy(getattr(self.klass, attr), **self.kwargs)


class Session:
    def __init__(self, token=None):
        self.token = token
        self.group1 = PartialProxyProxy(EndpointGroup, token=token)

class EndpointGroup:
    @classmethod
    def ping(cls, token, **kwargs):
        return f'Calling ping() with params: {kwargs} and token {token}'

session = Session(token='123')
r = session.group1.ping(data='somedata')
print(r)
```

Output:

```
Calling ping() with params: {'data': 'somedata'} and token 123
```

Comment: This way creates many instances of partialproxyproxy instead of instance of endpointgroups which still causes undesirable behavior described in my first attempt. How ever these proxies require less memory, so it partially solves problem. Thank you.

Comment: Anyway, seems if i can understand how it works, then i can create/call partialrpoxyproxy instance in session \__gettattr__ when "groupX" is called. So it seems that the instance will exist only during call and be destroyed after it.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Session:
    def __init__(self, token=None):
        self.token = token
        self.group1 = EndpointGroup

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        attribute = super(Session, self).__getattribute__(item)
        if isinstance(attribute, type(EndpointGroup)):
            return ProxyEndpointGroup(self.token,attribute)
        else:
            return attribute
```

```
import functools
class ProxyEndpointGroup:
    def __init__(self, token, endpoint_group):
        self.token = token
        self.endpoint_group = endpoint_group

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return functools.partial(getattr(self.endpoint_group,item), token=self.token)
```

```
class EndpointGroup:
    @classmethod
    def ping(cls,token, **kwargs):
        return f'Calling ping() with params: {kwargs} and token {token}'
```

```
session = Session(token='12345')
r = session.group1.ping(data='endpoint data')
print(r)

>> Calling ping() with params: {'data': 'endpoint data'} and token 12345
```

this way you can create the proxy object only on call add token param and return the partial method finally destroy the proxy object.

It solves your concern of not having to create multiple unnecessary objects in memory
It also solves the problem of async calls as token in passed in each call

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why `ping()` should be a class method instead of an instance method, and your problem gets easier if it's an instance method:

```
class Session:
    def __init__(self, token=None):
        self.token = token
        self.group1 = EndpointGroup(session=self)
```

Pass the session to the `EndpointGroup`, and then its instance method `ping` can access the token directly:

```
class EndpointGroup:
    def __init__(self, session):
        self.session = session
    def ping(self, token, **kwargs):
        return f'Calling ping() with params: {kwargs} and token {self.session.token}'
```

Comment: It seems wrong. for example: i have 20 EndpointGroups instances per 1 instance session. So, if some hypotetical web service will have 1000 sessions then it will have 20000 instances of endpointgroups. This situation does not seem right

Comment: @ArtemChirkov:  Why does one session need 20 endpoints?  Are you saying that if 574 of your 1000 sessions have endpoint "A" that there is no difference at all between those 574 endpoint "A"s?

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```py
class Session:
    class Empty:
        pass
    def __init__(self, token=None):
        self.token = token
        self.group1 = self.Empty
        setattr(self.group1, "ping", lambda p : EndpointGroup.ping(self.token, **p))

class EndpointGroup:
    @classmethod
    def ping(cls, token, **kwargs):
        return f'Calling ping() with params: {kwargs} and token {token}'
```

```
a = Session("123")
r = a.group1.ping({"param_key":"param_val"})
r
"Calling ping() with params: {'param_key': 'param_val'} and token 123"
```

Or second way (little bit closer to OOP on my opinion):

```py
class Session:
    def __init__(self, token=None):
        class EndpointGroupWithToken(EndpointGroup):
            @classmethod
            def ping(cls, **kwargs):
                return super().ping(self.token, **kwargs)
        self.token = token
        self.group1 = EndpointGroupWithToken

class EndpointGroup:
    @classmethod
    def ping(cls, token, **kwargs):
        return f'Calling ping() with params: {kwargs} and token {token}'
```

```
a = Session("123")
r = a.group1.ping(data='somedata')
r
"Calling ping() with params: {'data': 'somedata'} and token 123"
```

But I think that you chosen wrong architecture for your application. Maybe Mixins will be more fitable to your needs?

```
class Ping1Mixin:
    def ping1(self, **kwargs):
        return f'Calling ping1() with params: {kwargs} and token {self.token}'
        
class Ping2Mixin:
    def ping2(self, **kwargs):
        return f'Calling ping2() with params: {kwargs} and token {self.token}'
        
class Session(Ping1Mixin, Ping2Mixin):
    def __init__(self, token=None):
        self.token = token
```

```
a = Session("123")
r = a.ping1(data='somedata')
r = a.ping2(data='somedata')
```

Thank you for interesting puzzle :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have "sessions" and "endpoint groups" and they don't necessarily have to be tightly coupled. Assuming your api methods (eg. `ping`) don't have to be class methods (which they don't seem to need to be), then a simple solution is to create a session object and then provide that to an endpoint group object. You then have N number of unique session objects and M number of unique endpoint groups and compose endpoint groups as necessary to provide them with the correct tokens. That avoids the excessive amount of objects you seem to be trying to avoid.

Example:

```py
class Session:
    def __init__(self, token):
        self.token = token

class EndpointGroup:
    def __init__(self, session):
        self.session = session
    def ping(self, **kwargs):
        # do a ping

session_abc = Session('ABC')
session_xyz = Session('XYZ')

endpoint_group_1 = EndpointGroup(session_abc)
endpoint_group_2 = EndpointGroup(session_abc)
endpoint_group_3 = EndpointGroup(session_xyz)
```

If it seems like "extra work" to match sessions with endpoint groups, you can easily take care of that with a factory method.

Answer (score -1):

You should do it this way.
It will be correct answer in your case.

```
class Session:
    def __init__(self, token=None):
        self.token = token
        self.group1 = EndpointGroup(token)

class EndpointGroup:
    @classmethod
    def __init__(self, token=None):
        self.token = token
    def ping(self, **kwargs):
        return f'Calling ping() with params: {kwargs} and token {self.token}'
```

Execute:

```
session = Session(token='123')
r = session.group1.ping(data='somedata')
print(r)
```

Output:

```
"Calling ping() with params: {'data': 'somedata'} and token 123"
```

Comment: That is most bad solution! Very bad and wrong pattern! `session1=Session(token='123');session2=Session(token='567');r1=session1.group1.ping(data='somedata1');r2=session2.group1.ping(data='somedata2');print(r1);print(r2)` will print: `Calling ping() with params: {'data': 'somedata1'} and token 567` and `Calling ping() with params: {'data': 'somedata2'} and token 567`